# How to configure maven in android stuio?

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

i had been using eclipse .it was fine with m2 plugin.now i switched to android studio.i dont know how to convert my project to maven project.Any help would be appreciated?

P.s I installed maven in my windows 7. in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
mavenCentral()
 }

 dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mavenCentral()` is the [central repository](http://search.maven.org/) shorthand, it's like [this tag in the pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories).

`build.gradle` is a **Gradle** build system build file, to convert to **Maven** build system you need a `pom.xml`.

I suggest you import your existing project (which has the pom.xml) view *File > Import Project...* and select Maven during the import.

[Google's suggested way of building Android apps is with Android Studio, which tightly integrates with Gradle and that's the preferred and most advanced way of assembling apks for apps](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html).

## Referencing libs

Gradle has what Maven has and more.

```
<project>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.bumptech.glide</groupId>
    <artifactId>glide</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

is the same as (be careful this is not the same as `buildscript { dependencies { ... } }`)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.3.1'
}
```

See the Dependency Information in the Maven Central search for this lib: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.bumptech.glide%7Cglide%7C3.3.1%7Cjar

Comment: i want to use some third party libraries which is available in maven central.is it available in gradle also?

Comment: Maven central hold `jar` files, but Gradle has a built-in feature to handle Maven repositories, see update on what's the difference. Check the long link in the post, that'll describe everything.